# Interior, closure, accumulation ponts, compactness and conection of subsets in some topologies.

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some difficulties at the very start of the concepts of general topology.

For $\tau_1$ = co-countable topology, $\tau_2 = \{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a,+\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $\tau_3 = \{\emptyset\}\cup\{A\subset\mathbb{R} : 0 \in A\}$, define the interior, closure, accumulation points and if they are connected and compact for the following sets:

a) $\mathbb{Q}$

b) $(1,2]$

c) $C=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

For $\tau_1$, I think that:

$int(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset, cl(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}' = \emptyset$

And that's all that I could think, I'm really struggling with that.

Comment: Please be a little more specific in what you will like help in! Some work will very appreciated!

Comment: Help to define the things I've listed for that list of sets, I'll add my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\tau_1$: note that $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so closed, and indeed cannot contain any co-countable subset so its interior is empty. $\Bbb Q$ is also discrete so indeed $\Bbb Q'=\emptyset$, so far so good.

$(1,2]$ is not countable so is not contained in any proper closed subset, so $\operatorname{cl}((1,2]) = \Bbb R$ and also it doesn't contain any co-countable set because the complement is uncountable hence the interior is $\emptyset$; being dense of course $(1,2]' = \Bbb R$ too.

$C$ is countable and discrete and the same ideas that work for $\Bbb Q$ work for it too: so empty interior, $C'=\emptyset$ and closure just $C$.

For $\tau_2$ (the upper topology) we have that the closure of any set without upper bound is $\Bbb R$ so this holds for $\Bbb Q$. The largest proper closed set (which are of the form $(-\infty, a]$ containing $B$ is $(-\infty,2]$ so that is its closure, and the largest one containing $C$ is $(-\infty,1]$, so that's its closure. None of the three sets contain an upper set $(a,+\infty)$ so there interior are all $\emptyset$. Its clear that all points of $\Bbb R$ that are $\le 1$ are limit points of $C$, so $C'=(-\infty,1]$, its closure. $\Bbb Q'=\Bbb R$ here too and we too have that $(1,2]' = (-\infty,2]$.

For $\tau_3$ (the included point topology wrt $0$) we have that $0 \in \Bbb Q$ so $\operatorname{int}(\Bbb Q) = \Bbb Q$ and $\operatorname{int}((1,2])=\emptyset$ as no non-empty open set can be contained in $(1,2]$ as $0 \notin (1,2]$ but also $\operatorname{int}(C)=C$ as $0 \in C$ and so $C$ is open. If $0 \in D$ then $\operatorname{cl}(D)=\Bbb R$ for $\tau_3$ so this holds for $\Bbb Q$ and $C$ both. If $0 \notin D$, then $\operatorname{cl}(D) = D$ as then the complement of $D$ is open. Also, if $0 \in D$ then $D'=\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ as easily follows from the definition. If $0 \notin D$, then $D'=\emptyset$ (any point $x$ has a neighbourhood $\{x,0\}$ that then can intersect $D$ only in $x$ if at all). This settles all derived sets.

I'll leave connectedness and compactness to the interested reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!